# unable to send/receive email in cpanel - SMTP error (504): authentication failed

Tags: email, smtp, roundcube

I cant send Email in Roundcube webmail, when click to send I have this error: **SMTP error (504): authentication failed**

I use CSF firewall and mail port is open. SMTP_ALLOWLOCAL is on, SMTP_BLOCK in on/off not defference, (I disable CSF but i have same error. Even if I remove CSF completely, the same error still exists.)

I use Cloadflare on my whm hostname and my main domain, but cloudflare setting is defult. and my hostname is dns-only.

My OS is ubuntu 20.04 with litespeed webserver.

I change my email account password but I have same error.

in this log: /var/log/exim_mainlog.1 I have many time this error:

```
2024-01-07 10:30:01 1rM5Gd-009brq-1z Message is frozen
```

RDNS is my hostname in Hetzner Cloud and my PTR record is valid.

Also: Exim is not listed service restart menu whm. Exim is not listed service status page whm. even after checking via terminal the status of exim, the reply is always:

```
root@server:~# service exim restart
Failed to restart exim.service: Unit exim.service not found.
```

but Exim Configuration Manager in ok in WHM.

I guess the problem is exim. Is there a way to reinstall/install/repair it? I reset it from Exim Configuration Manager but the problem is still there.

Can I install exim in ubuntu? Does this not cause a crash in Cpanel? Which package should be installed exactly?

```
root@server:~# apt install exim
Package exim is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it:
cpanel-exim exim4-base
```

Comment: The error says there is an authentication failure, so there is no blockage, you're just passing the wrong username and password or the wrong authentication method to the backend. There should be no need to reinstall things or the like, just make sure you have your configuration in RoundCube (and Exim?) set up correctly. It looks like your hosting provider did that for you, so check with their support department first.

Comment: @zwets As explained, I can log in to the Roundcube panel, but I can't send or receive emails, so there is no problem with the username and password. There is also hosting support! According to my explanation, it is clear that the VPS and its access are ours.

Comment: The issue is not with the login to RoundCube but with _its_ authentication to its backend. Check if you have configured that correctly. What are your backend SMTP and IMAP servers? Are you self hosting those? In that case, you will have configured their authentication settings (as well as all other things like adding the MX and SPF records, DKIM, etc), so double check that they match what you have configured in RoundCube.

Comment: TNX @zwets . I am using cPanel on the server and all the settings have been done by installing cPanel, but after installing CSF on the server, sending and receiving emails broke. Now, even after deleting CSF, there is still a problem with emails. MX records and... also have no problem with checking customer domains on IntoDNS site. Except for one: MX name validity. The MX records that do not seem valid hostname:
_dc-mx.c87f167142e6.tokanweb.com
This can cause problems